# android (multitouch) drawing app undone function

Tags: android, canvas, path, hashmap

I am working on a drawing app, the `onTouchEvents` are standard, and would like to add `Undo()` function to remove the last drawn path.

**Declarations:**

```
int thelastLineId=0;
private Bitmap bitmap; // drawing area for display or saving
private Canvas bitmapCanvas; // used to draw on bitmap
private Paint paintScreen; // use to draw bitmap onto screen
private Paint paintLine; // used to draw lines onto bitmap
private HashMap<Integer, Path> pathMap; // current Paths being drawn
private HashMap<Integer, Path> reservedpathMap; // for saving the paths being undone
private HashMap<Integer, Point> previousPointMap; // current Points
```

**Constructor:**

```
pathMap = new HashMap<Integer, Path>();
reservedpathMap = new HashMap <Integer,Path>(); // for storing path being undone
previousPointMap = new HashMap<Integer, Point>();
```

**onDraw:**

```
   @Override
   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
   {
       canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paintScreen);
       // for each path currently being drawn
       for (Integer key : pathMap.keySet()) 
            canvas.drawPath(pathMap.get(key), paintLine); // draw line     
   }
```

**onTouchEvent:**

```
   @Override
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
   {                  
      int action = event.getActionMasked(); // event type 
      int actionIndex = event.getActionIndex(); // pointer (i.e., finger)

      if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
      {       
          touchStarted(event.getX(actionIndex), event.getY(actionIndex), event.getPointerId(actionIndex));
      } 
      else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) 
      {
          touchEnded(event.getPointerId(actionIndex));
      } 
      else 
      {
         touchMoved(event); 
      } 

      invalidate();
      return true; 
   }
```

**touchStarted:**

```
   private void touchStarted(float x, float y, int lineID) // lineID represents how many fingers, 1 finger 1 line
   {      
      Path path; // used to store the path for the given touch id
      Point point; // used to store the last point in path

      // if there is already a path for lineID
      if (pathMap.containsKey(lineID)) 
      {
         path = pathMap.get(lineID); // get the Path
         path.reset(); // reset the Path because a new touch has started
         point = previousPointMap.get(lineID); // get Path's last point
      } 
      else 
      {
         path = new Path(); // create a new Path
         pathMap.put(lineID, path); // add the Path to Map
         point = new Point(); // create a new Point
         previousPointMap.put(lineID, point); // add the Point to the Map
      } 

      path.moveTo(x, y);
      point.x = (int) x;  
      point.y = (int) y;  
   }
```

**touchMoved:**

```
   private void touchMoved(MotionEvent event) 
   {
      // for each of the pointers in the given MotionEvent
      for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) 
      {
         // get the pointer ID and pointer index
         int pointerID = event.getPointerId(i);
         int pointerIndex = event.findPointerIndex(pointerID);

         // if there is a path associated with the pointer
         if (pathMap.containsKey(pointerID)) 
         {
            float newX = event.getX(pointerIndex);
            float newY = event.getY(pointerIndex);

            // get the Path and previous Point associated with this pointer
            Path path = pathMap.get(pointerID);
            Point point = previousPointMap.get(pointerID);

            float deltaX = Math.abs(newX - point.x);
            float deltaY = Math.abs(newY - point.y);
            if (deltaX >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || deltaY >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) 
            {
               path.quadTo(point.x, point.y, ((newX + point.x)/2),((newY + point.y)/2));

               point.x = (int) newX ; 
               point.y = (int) newY ; 
         } 
      }      
   }
```

**touchEnded:**

```
   private void touchEnded(int lineID)
   {
      Path path = pathMap.get(lineID); // get the corresponding Path
      bitmapCanvas.drawPath(path, paintLine); 
      path.reset();           
   }
```

**UNDO:**

```
   public void undo()
   {
       Toast.makeText(getContext(), "undo button pressed" + thelastLineId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       Path path = pathMap.get(thelastLineId); 
       reservedpathMap.put(thelastLineId, path); // add the Path to reservedpathMap for later redo
       pathMap.remove(thelastLineId);   

       invalidate();          
   }
```

### **Question:**

I am trying to implement the UNDO method using the code as shown above: trying to remove the `thelastLindId` key from the `HashMap` `pathmap` (and put to `HashMap reservedpathMap` for later Redo) such that when `invalidate()` it will invoke the `OnDraw()` and to redraw by

```
for (Integer key : pathMap.keySet()) 
                canvas.drawPath(pathMap.get(key), paintLine);
```

However, pressing the undo button can initiate the toast of "undo is clicked" but the last drawn line fails to disappear.

Could anybody please give me a clue for the Undo() and Redo() ? Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: Are you sure that this piece of code actually is removing the last line? Have you ever checked the size of your hashmap and the values inside of it?

Comment: I have just added a Toast.makeText(getContext(), "touchEnded" + pathMap.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); at TouchEnded method and tried to draw so as to show the toast. I discovered that when using 1 finger to draw at 1st time, it shows size = 1, however, when using 1 finger to go on draw 2nd line, it still shows size = 1.  I then further tried using 2 fingers for 3rd and 4th line at the same time it then shows size =2. Using back 1 finger draws the 5th line size shows 2. Using 3 fingers draw 6,7,8th line it shows size = 3. I really dont know why.

Answer (score 1):

As I can understand what you want to achieve, you want to be able to draw lines on canvas and after that make UNDO functionality to your project. First of all I think the moment when you add the path to your array should be when the user lift his finger , in your `touchEnded` method. Second of all I don't really get the thing which you are explaining about two / three fingers? Are you supporting multi touch in your canvas? Here is an implementation which I was using before in some example for drawing on canvas with undo implementation. Hope it will help you to make the things more clear :

```
public void onClickUndo () { 
if (paths.size()>0) { 
   undonePaths.add(paths.remove(paths.size()-1))
   invalidate();
 }
    else
     //toast the user 
}

public void onClickRedo (){
   if (undonePaths.size()>0) { 
       paths.add(undonePaths.remove(undonePaths.size()-1)) 
       invalidate();
   } 
   else 
     //toast the user 
}
```

and here are the equalents of your touch methods :

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {            

    for (Path p : paths){
        canvas.drawPath(p, mPaint);
    }

}

private float mX, mY;
private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 0;

private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
    mPath.reset();
    mPath.moveTo(x, y);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
}
private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
    if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
        mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
}
private void touch_up() {
    mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
    // commit the path to our offscreen
    mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    // kill this so we don't double draw            
    mPath = new Path();
    paths.add(mPath);
}
```

As you can see from here paths is the arraylist where I am storing my paths. If you tell me why you need to put your paths in hashmap maybe I can be more helpful.

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed answer!  For the 2 or 3 fingers i am referring above yup the drawing view support multitouch and toast reports size of hashmap =2 when using 2 fingers at same time and 3 if use 3 fingers drawing at the same time.  Afterwards if using 1 finger back it will still show size =3

Comment: i have just at the same time using your above code to form out a non-multitouch drawing code. everythings work fine using path array. Yet when i am implementing the undo as you shown above, it does not work and 2 questions arised, as shown in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14960152/android-drawing-app-undo-method-not-working-properly, just would like to know if you have any clue on this =) many thanks!!