# android (singletouch) drawing app undo method not working properly

Tags: android, canvas, path, bitmap, touch-event

I am working on a drawing app but facing some undo problems. The coding is as follows:

```
public class DoodleView extends View 
{
    Context context_new;

    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 5;
    private Bitmap bitmap; // drawing area for display or saving
    private Canvas bitmapCanvas; // used to draw on bitmap
    private Paint paintScreen; // use to draw bitmap onto screen
    private Paint paintLine; // used to draw lines onto bitmap

    private Path mPath; 
    private ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
    private ArrayList<Path> undonePaths = new ArrayList<Path>();
    private float mX, mY;

   // DoodleView constructor initializes the DoodleView
   public DoodleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
   {
       super(context, attrs); // pass context to View's constructor
       this.context_new=context;

       paintScreen = new Paint(); // used to display bitmap onto screen

       // set the initial display settings for the painted line
       paintLine = new Paint();
       paintLine.setAntiAlias(true); // smooth edges of drawn line
       paintLine.setColor(Color.BLACK); // default color is black
       paintLine.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE); // solid line

       mPath = new Path();
       paths.add(mPath);

   } // end DoodleView constructor
```

**OnSizeChanged:**

```
   @Override
   public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldW, int oldH)
   {
      super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldW, oldH);
      DoodlzViewWidth = w;     
      DoodlzViewHeight = h;

      bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), DoodlzViewHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

      bitmapCanvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
      bitmap.eraseColor(Color.WHITE); // erase the BitMap with white 
   }
```

**onDraw:**

```
   @Override
   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)  
   {
       canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paintScreen); 
       // for each path currently being drawn
       for (Path p : paths){canvas.drawPath(p, paintLine);}                
   }
```

**onTouchEvent:**

```
   @Override
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
   {          
          float x = event.getX();
          float y = event.getY();

          switch (event.getAction())
          {
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                  touchStarted(x, y);
                  invalidate();
                  break;
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                  touchMoved(x, y);
                  invalidate();
                  break;
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                  touchEnded();
                  invalidate();
                  break;
          }
          return true;
    }
```

**touchStarted:**

```
   private void touchStarted(float x, float y) 
   {
       mPath.reset();
       mPath.moveTo(x, y);
       mX = x;
       mY = y;
   }
```

**touchMoved:**

```
   private void touchMoved(float x, float y) 
   {
       float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
       float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
       if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) 
       {
           mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
           mX = x;
           mY = y;               
       }
   }
```

**touchEnded:**

```
   private void touchEnded() 
   {
      mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);      
      bitmapCanvas.drawPath(mPath, paintLine);
      mPath = new Path();
      paths.add(mPath);
      Toast.makeText(getContext(), "touchEnded" + paths.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
```

**Undo:**

```
public void onClickUndo() 
{ 
   Toast.makeText(getContext(), "before undo button pressed " + paths.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
   if (paths.size()>0) 
    { 
       undonePaths.add(paths.remove(paths.size()-1));
       Toast.makeText(getContext(), "after undo button pressed " + paths.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       Log.i("UNDOING", "PREPARE INVALIDATE");
       invalidate();
       Log.i("UNDOING", "FINISH INVALIDATE");
    }      
   else Toast.makeText(getContext(), "nothing to undo" + paths.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
}
```

### **Question:**

The above is sourced from other examples searched online. Dont know why need to set path.reset() when implementing `touchStarted`?

Q1. When I press the undo the button, it would properly show the `toast` undo button pressed, and reporting the `path.size()` being 0, and hence the immediately previously drawn line is **not removed**. I really dont know why it is 0?? Isnt it added to the path array already? How could the code be modified?

** code modified after taking android-developer's advice! Thanks!! It now correctly showing path.size(). Sorry for the silly missing out!* **But the previous line drawn is still cannot be removed? =(**

Q2. While the app is functioning properly when the finger is moving on the screen and showing the line immediately, When I press the undo the button, in addition to the above that previous line is not removed, the lines further draw to the screen after pressing the button will not show out until the finger is lifted.

**answer to Q2:**
moving the below 2 lines from `touchEnded()` to `touchStarted()`

```
mPath = new Path();
paths.add(mPath);
```

.

```
   private void touchStarted(float x, float y) 
   {
       mPath.reset();
       mPath = new Path();
       paths.add(mPath);
       mPath.moveTo(x, y);
       mX = x;
       mY = y;
   }

   private void touchEnded() 
   {
       mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);      
       bitmapCanvas.drawPath(mPath, paintLine);// commit the path to our offscreen                   
       Toast.makeText(getContext(), "touchEnded" + paths.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: I can't see `paths.add(mPath);` after `mPath.reset();`. where are you adding your current path to your arraylist?

Comment: thanks for your advice!! I have amended the silly missing-out mistake! The path.size() can now be showing correctly, ie. when drawing one more line the size will increase by 1. Yet the previously path still cannot be removed (though toast undo shows out), and the strange drawing effect when pressed the button: the line wont appear when drawing until finger is removed.

Comment: you are saying that even paths.size() is bigger than 0, the `undo button pressed` toast shows up?

Comment: undo part coding updated..it will show "undo button pressed4" if 4 line is drawn. thanks for your prompt reply~

Comment: can you check something for me, after pressing undo button is it actually removing the last path from the arraylist and is if calling `onDraw()` method after `invalidate()` ?

Comment: thanks for help v much..! the toast in undo is amended as above, after drawing 4 lines, when press undo button, it will first toast "before undo button pressed 4", then displays "after undo button pressed 3". how to see whether it is calling OnDraw()?

Comment: put a Log in onDraw and watch the LogCat.It's more efficient than adding Toasts everywhere.

Comment: i have put Log.i("UNDOING", "PREPARE INVALIDATE") before invalidate and Log.i("UNDOING", "FINISH INVALIDATE") after invalidate in the Undo method; and put Log.i("OnDRAWING", "REACH ON DRAW") in onDraw. The logcat shows 02-20 00:43:21.833: I/UNDOING(5480): PREPARE INVALIDATE
02-20 00:43:21.833: I/UNDOING(5480): FINISH INVALIDATE
02-20 00:43:22.018: I/OnDRAWING(5480): REACH ON DRAW

Comment: would it matter if in constructor already has mPath = new Path(); and 
       paths.add(mPath); ?

Comment: problem solved, i discover that in onDraw there is canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paintScreen); if it is removed, everything then work fine!

Comment: happy to hear that man, sorry i was away for a few days and i couldn't help you.

Comment: thanks your help all along the way! btw can you put up an answer so that i could accept it as actually it is most of your effort because I mostly modify from your answer in that multitouch drawing app undo problem...=) your helps cannot be neglected!

Comment: go vote the other question if you want, but best option is to write the answer yourself so someone else who is trying to implement it can find it too. : )

Comment: @pearmak As u said that removing canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paintScreen); will solve the error...But my question is if i want to show the saved image onto the canvas then it will not work if i dont used canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paintScreen);...so then what to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### updated and works:

1. removed Paint paintScreen;
2. in onDraw do not put `canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paintScreen);`  or `canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paintLine);`

   ```
   private Bitmap bitmap; // drawing area for display or saving
   private Canvas bitmapCanvas; // used to draw on bitmap
   private Paint paintLine; // used to draw lines onto bitmap   
   private Path mPath; 
   private ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
   private ArrayList<Path> undonePaths = new ArrayList<Path>();
   private float mX, mY;
   private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;    

   // DoodleView constructor initializes the DoodleView

   public DoodleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
   {
      super(context, attrs); // pass context to View's constructor
      this.context_new=context;
      setFocusable(true);
      setFocusableInTouchMode(true);      

      // set the initial display settings for the painted line
      paintLine = new Paint();
      paintLine.setAntiAlias(true); // smooth edges of drawn line
      paintLine.setDither(true);
      paintLine.setColor(Color.BLACK); // default color is black
      paintLine.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE); // solid line
      paintLine.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
      paintLine.setStrokeWidth(5); // set the default line width
      paintLine.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND); // rounded line ends

      bitmapCanvas = new Canvas();
      mPath = new Path();            
    } // end DoodleView constructor

    // Method onSizeChanged creates BitMap and Canvas after app displays

    @Override
    public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldW, int oldH)
    {
       super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldW, oldH);
       DoodlzViewWidth = w;       
       DoodlzViewHeight = h;           
    } 

    @Override

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
    {         
      for (Path p : paths){canvas.drawPath(p, paintLine);}  
      canvas.drawPath(mPath, paintLine);
      Log.i("OnDRAWING", "REACH ON DRAW");        
   }
   ```

   // START TOUCH: handle touch event
        @Override

   ```
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
    {            
         float x = event.getX();
         float y = event.getY();

         switch (event.getAction())
         {
             case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                 touch_start(x, y);
                 invalidate();
                 break;
             case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touch_move(x, y);
                 invalidate();
                 break;
             case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                 touch_up();
                 invalidate();
                 break;
         }
         return true;
   }

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) 
    {
      undonePaths.clear();
      mPath.reset();
      mPath.moveTo(x, y);
      mX = x;
      mY = y;
   }

   private void touch_move(float x, float y) 
   {
       float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
       float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
       if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) 
       {
           mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
           mX = x;
           mY = y;
       }
   }  

   private void touch_up() 
   {
       mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);      
       bitmapCanvas.drawPath(mPath, paintLine);// commit the path to our offscreen  
       paths.add(mPath);
       mPath = new Path(); 
   }

   public void onClickUndo() 
   { 
      if (paths.size()>0) 
       { 
          undonePaths.add(paths.remove(paths.size()-1));
          invalidate();
       }      
      else Toast.makeText(getContext(), "nothing more to undo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
   }
   ```